# How do I initialise a Object that I need throughout the app? Android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and currently working on a project. I need a `object` initialized which I would normally put in the main class, however being Android I can not do that. I tried the main activity `onCreate()` but, then it initializes it every time the main activity is opened. This means it resets all of the variables that I need within the object.

If I haven't explained anything correctly, just ask.

Kind Regards,
Dan

Comment: If you need data to persist even after your app is closed, you should save it to a file, just like in a desktop app.

Comment: Yes, I will be doing that later on. But for now I didn't want to do that for testing. At the moment I want the data to reset when I reload the app.

Comment: Please describe in more detail where you need to use the object. Do you have more than one Activity? Are you using Fragments? Which ones of these will share the object?

Comment: Well written automated tests should not rely on any previously existing state. Even if your app saves data to disk, tests should create the expected data when they start and erase all data created during the entire test after they finish.

Comment: If you are testing by hand, I strongly encourage you to look at the Testing Support Library and start writing automated tests.

Comment: If you don't want to persist the data to a file, you can use a what's known as a singleton. A singleton is essentially a class which is initialised only once during the lifetime of the application, and can be accessed via a static reference.
[here is some info on the singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: I will look into the automated tests, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. It's only created once when the Application starts and you can use it as a singleton class to store application wide data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this has done the job I needed. I would upvote but I have a new account so don't have enough rep

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you need a *kind* of singleton that persist over multiple starts?

For that, you can use a lot of thing like:

- SharedPreferences => [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#GetSharedPreferences)
- SQLite => [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)
- Files => [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

If it's "just" a singleton, you can add it to the ***application*** class.

Comment: At the moment this isn't what I need but I will be using SQLite or files to store the data. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Singleton pattern. By using single pattern due to its static nature you will be able to access that object of singleton across all the app

Comment: why downvoted? Please give the reason so i can update my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you, someone downvoted everyones answers at some point. I tried upvoting but don't have enough reputation

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom class of `Application` or use a singleton.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate a bit on this answer, to make it more complete? Maybe provide an example?